# Turn dropzone on / off dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js

I've been trying to utilize the dropzone.js plugin and would be grateful for anyone's thoughts who is more experienced at this one,  as documentation on the net seems to be sparse.  The below code segment essentially demonstrates what I'm trying to do.

```
    <script>
    for (j=1; j<=5; j++) { // set photo boxes, these can be revisited later
        picname = './pics/'+pic[j];
         // custom function, after php the function, returns true if file exists
        if (file_exists(picname)) {
          // show picture (possibly dropzone-generated thumbnail?)
          $("#photo"+j).html('<img src="'+picname+'"><br>'+name[j]);
        } else {
            $("#photo"+j).dropzone({
              url: 'picupload.php'
            });
        }
    }
    </script>

    <div id="photo1"></div>
    <div id="photo2"></div>
    <div id="photo3"></div>
    <div id="photo4"></div>
    <div id="photo5"></div>
```

Each div'd photo container should at any time be able to switch back and forth from a dropzone to a display of an uploaded photo if it exists.  I've scaled back the configuration parameters of the dropzone and omitted the css for clarity sake.

I would also like to know if it's possible to leverage the thumbnail-generating aspects of dropzone.js to save/show thumbnails of uploaded files (images).